# Proof: Determinant of cofactors is square of determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove that for a 3x3 matrix:

$$\varDelta^c=\varDelta^2$$
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 & B_1 & C_1 \\
    A_2 & B_2 & C_2 \\
    A_3 & B_3 & C_3 
  \end{bmatrix}
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_2c_3-c_2b_3 & c_2a_3-a_2c_3 & a_2b_3-b_2a_3 \\
    a_2c_3-c_2a_3 & a_1c_3-a_3c_1 & a_1c_2-a_2c_1 \\
    a_2b_3-a_3b_2 & a_1b_3-a_3b_1 & a_1b_2-a_2b_1
  \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
    a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
    a_3 & b_3 & c_3
  \end{bmatrix}^2
$$

---

Trying to expand the left hand results in an unhandlable expression. I couldn't find this proof with a simple search either.

Comment: Do you know a result about the product of a square matrix and the matrix of its signed cofactors?  That result is closely related to using expansion by minors to compute a matrix determinant.

Comment: @hardmath I haven't studied that. If you can point me a name or link, it would be really appreciated.